# In how many ways can the letters of the word BANANA be rearranged such that the new word does not begin with a *B*?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the letters of the word BANANA be rearranged such that the new word does not begin with a B?

What I did is incorrect. I said there are $5$ choices for the first place and then $5!$ possibilities after that for a total of $5\cdot5!=600$. However, I think I need to divide by $2$ and $3$ because of the repetitions of N and A. So how many ways can I do this? What am I missing?

Comment: You do need to take the repeats of A and N into account.  But you don't divide by 3 because there are 3 As.  You divide by ... well, what would be your hypothesis?

Comment: Divide by 2!3!?

Comment: That's a good hypothesis.  Now, to just figure out whether it is true or not.... (hint:  it is)

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative solution: choose the place for B, then choose the subset of places that contain an A, and this determines the word.

For B you have 5 options. For the set of positions with an A on them you have ${5}\choose{3}$ options.

Your total is $5*{{5}\choose{3}}=50$ words.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Suppose there is no restriction, the number of possibilities to arrange BANANA would be $\frac{6!}{2!3!}$.

Now suppose we want the first letter to be $B$. how many ways are there to arrange ANANA?

Use the first quantity to subtract the second quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases: all As and Ns are different. In this case for each allocation of B you have 5! allocations of ANANA. Hence the solution is 5!5.

Case 2:  all As are the same, all Ns are the same.  For each allocation of B you choose $\binom{5}{3}$ positions for As. So the solution is 5 $\times \binom{5}{3}$.